# What is the most efficient way to connect to IBM DB2 database using CLION?

Tags: db2, clion

I am new to CPP programming (this is my first post actually) and I'm now trying to dive into the SQL databases and educate myself a bit more. I managed to create a database and a table on it and also managed to find it and view my schemas in the database section of the ide. Well now I would like to find a way to write some code to connect or disconnect the DB, to run queries (update a table if an attribute is changed) and so forth. Is it better to use a library or an API or what? Is there any plugin for CLION to make my life easier?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[CLION docs actually describe how to set up a connection to Db2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-db2-database). The Db2 docs give some background about the [different types of drivers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0023452.html) and how to install them. There are full packages which include all the necessary drivers or smaller, more focussed packs.

The answer API or SDK or ... depends on the solution and its requirements. All is supported.